# maven dependency plugin gives error

Tags: maven

In my maven project i delete all jars from lib and i specify all the jars as dependencies in POM.XML,I specify the plugins maven war plugin,maven compiler plugin.

At first while update the project using update maven project,it gives error for that i change the settings.XML file content **jst.web 3.0 to 2.4** now it works fine,

Now i would like to store all the dependencies specified in POM.XML into ${project}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib when i run maven install,for that i place maven-dependency-plugin in the POM.XML,But it gives different error without any error information.

maven-dependency-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
         <phase>install</phase>
         <goals>
           <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
           <outputDirectory>WebContent/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

here the jars are stored but it gives error

Error is: `Unknown  Validation Message`

can you please help to me.

Comment: Can you show the full log output furthermore why are you using `${project}/WebContent/...` in Maven you should use `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib` which is by default used and not needed to do by maven-dependency-plugin. Can you show your pom as well.

Comment: These jars are stored in WebContent/WEB-INF/lib but it gives the error to show my POM.XML it gives some error while editing.I made the change in settings.XML file(change 3.0 to 2.4),can the jars stored in the web-inf directly

Comment: What kind of change do you need to make to your settings.xml? Your pom file is the correct location nor did you answer my question: Where is the full output of the error? and why are you going to use `WebContent/..` instead of the default folder layout?

Comment: Error:Description Resource Path Location Type
 DishaAPIServer  Unknown Validation Message. I want to store all the dependencies in the specified in POM.XML into WebContent/WEB-INF/lib for my future use

Comment: For what purpose and use case are you using the content of WebContent/WEB-INF/lib ? Apart from that if you create WAR archive all dependencies will automatically be put into WEB-INF/lib so i don't see the need to do such things manually via dependency-plugin...?